# is there a way to write Salesforce Devoloper Console like scripts on a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, salesforce, apex, soql

in salesforce I was able to create scripts that could filter and manipulate data and then export a result. I'm new to mysql and I was wondering if there was a similar tool that uses some programming language to do the same?

here's an example of a salesforce script written in apex just to know what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Err , SQL is a programming language (and you have lumps of sql in your question). And export to what/where?

Comment: ok maybe I wasn't clear salesforce uses a language similar to mysql called soql (Salesforce Object Query Language) and I can write scripts that can go through a list and filter it then query the result etc. in salesforce but in mysql workbench I can only use queries. I'm looking for a tool that allows me to write scripts using the data pulled from the queries

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce implements a non relational database and a especific language to access to it called Salesforce Object Query Language (SOQL), very similar to SQL

APEX es a Java-like language to call that kind of queries (and more things). The advantage is that the same server hosts the db and the APEX server.

In mysql you have the freedom to choose any language (PHP, Java...) to access the data, but you have to install your own application server (apache, nginx...) to deploy your 
scripts.

Hope it helps

Comment: so if I install an application server like apache I can write similar scripts using java for example?